# LIKE in SQLite (and even MysQL)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sql-like

Will the LIKE keyword use the index in SQLite and/or MySQL?

I would understand that a wildcard match might not use the index, but how about a starts with comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends:

```
WHERE field1 LIKE 'test'  << can use index
WHERE field1 LIKE 'test%' << can also use index
WHERE field1 LIKE '%test' << cannot use index
WHERE field1 LIKE '_test' << cannot use index
```

As long as the wildcard is at the start, no index can be used. If you have fixed data before a wildcard, then an index can be used.

Some db's such as PostgreSQL have tricks that allow the use of indexes in all cases, but MySQL and SQLite do not.

Comment: Makes sense - and I now know that this is true for MySQL.  SQLite, too?

Comment: @Anthony: Yep, this is also true for SQLite.

Comment: Thanks.  I totally missed the second sentence for some reason.  Sorry for the reiterated question.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you: [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: Yes, thanks.  This all makes sense.  I'm guessing that SQLite would be very similar, but would you happen to know?  I couldn't find it at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html